# Keeping SKSpriteNode in bounds of screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, cgpoint, sprite-kit

I am trying to check whether my SKSpriteNode will remain in bounds of the screen during a drag gesture. I've gotten to the point where I am pretty sure my logic toward approaching the problem is right, but my implementation is wrong. Basically, before the player moves from the translation, the program checks to see whether its in bounds. Here is my code:

```
 -(CGPoint)checkBounds:(CGPoint)newLocation{
     CGSize screenSize = self.size;
     CGPoint returnValue = newLocation;
     if (newLocation.x <= self.player.position.x){
     returnValue.x = MIN(returnValue.x,0);
     } else {
       returnValue.x = MAX(returnValue.x, screenSize.width);
     }

     if (newLocation.y <= self.player.position.x){
     returnValue.y = MIN(-returnValue.y, 0);
     } else {
     returnValue.y = MAX(returnValue.y, screenSize.height);
     }

     NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGPoint(returnValue));
     return returnValue;
}
-(void)dragPlayer: (UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture {
          CGPoint translation = [gesture translationInView:self.view];

          CGPoint newLocation = CGPointMake(self.player.position.x + translation.x, self.player.position.y - translation.y);
    self.player.position = [self checkBounds:newLocation];
}
```

For some reason, my player is going off screen. I think my use of the MIN & MAX macros may be wrong, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly, you mixed up MIN/MAX. The line `MIN(x, 0)` will return the lower value of x or 0, meaning the result will be 0 or less.

At one line you're using `-returnValue.y` which makes no sense.

You can (and should for readability) omit the if/else because MIN/MAX, if used correctly, make if/else unnecessary here.

Comment: Question. Is using BOTH min and max redundant? Or will the compiler know which one to choose?

Comment: No, you have to apply both MIN/MAX one after the other to cap the location to a specific rectangle. Only the if/else is superfluous because they express essentially the same thing as the MIN/MAX macros (or use if/else but without the MIN/MAX macros because you already know in each instance that for example y < 0 and then just set y = 0.